# Simple Objective C String manipulation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

I have file names in the following format

```
filename_ffffff.png
filename2_cccccc.png
...
```

How can I manipulate this string and replace its hex value with a value of my choosing.

say the new value is `fffccc` which would take `filename_ffffff.png` and turn it into `filename_fffccc.png`

```
-(NSString *)replace:(NSString *)input with:(NSString *)newHex{
//find in input a patern of 6 char hex followed by dot png
// remove it from the string
// add the newHex followed by png
}
```

Comment: Are all your images in PNG format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(NSString *)replace:(NSString *)input with:(NSString *)newHex
{
    NSArray *seperated = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.png", [seperated objectAtIndex:0], newHex];
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one thumbs up. Did not know you can separate like that.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean

```
newstring = [oldstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ffffff.png" withString:@"cccccc.png"];
```

Comment: I think he don't know the hex string in first place so he need to take it. If it's a fixed format, you can use componentsSeparatedByString with "_" char and take the second element of the returning array.

Comment: Exactly what @BoranA said. I dont know if its ffffff or cccccc. I just need to replace all of it with that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change the occurrence of the string value. Check this :

```
NSString *Str = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"ffffff.png" withString:@"fffccc"];
```